# Open a Shell Program, pass it params, and return the results

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I'm writing a shell script in c++, and I'm trying to write a way to make some basic unit tests by comparing the output generated by the runtime of system and my shell diff-wise.

Based on reading through alot of StackOverflow articles, this is what I am using to capture the output of a simple ls command:

```
FILE *syst;
char buff[512];
string systout ( "" );
if(!(syst = popen("ls ", "r"))){
    cout << "Failed! " << endl;
    return 1;
}

while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), syst)!=NULL){
    systout.append(buff);
}

fflush(syst);   

pclose(syst);
```

This works just fine.

The issue is I cannot find a way of getting this to work for my shell script.
Normally I run it using `sudo ./shell`, then `ls`.

This is what I have right now, but it doesn't work. I think its not finding my shell or something, but there's nothing outputted. I know the shell works, because I've manually run it, and the results match the expected results.

```
FILE *shel;
char buff2[512];
string shelout ( "" );
if(!(shel = popen("sudo ./shell ls ", "r"))){
    cout << "Failed! " << endl;
    return 1;
}

while(fgets(buff2, sizeof(buff2), shel)!=NULL){
    shelout.append(buff2);
}

fflush(shel);

pclose(shel);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "Normally I run it using `sudo ./shell`, then `ls`." So it appears to me this is not the same thing as running `sudo ./shell ls`. Maybe you want to write the string `ls` to STDIN of the subprocess?

Comment: You should likely be running your program with `sudo` and calling the script without prefixing it, but it depends what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "Normally I run it using sudo ./shell, then ls", what you are saying is:

1. You execute "sudo", passing it one argument "./shell".
2. sudo runs "./shell" (as root, but that's not relevant here).
3. The "shell" executable prompts for a command of some kind, you type "ls" and you get the output.

You are attempting to automate it via the following piece of code:

```
popen("sudo ./shell ls ", "r")
```

What this does is

1. Executes "sudo", and passes the "sudo" command two arguments: "./shell" and "ls".

Which is completely different than happens in the first part, steps 1 through 3; and which is why it doesn't work.

The simplest thing for you to do is to modify your "./shell" to support alternative invocation means of passing it commands as arguments, instead of having "./shell" prompt interactively for commands to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `script` command for capturing your input and output.
Afterwards you can compare the output for both cases (using `diff` or `cmp` and filtering the differences with a simple program).